# Why VLC couldn't play .mp4 properly?

Tags: opensuse, vlc

Parole Media Player can play .mp4 properly on openSUSE 15.5, perhaps openSUSE 15.5 has enough codecs. While VLC only can play sound, and a few seconds of .mp4 video, how to set VLC to get over this problem without installing extra codecs?

Comment: Add in the question the result of ffprobe video.mp4 because you can't be sure for video format by file extension

Comment: Most media players depend on system installed codecs; VLC uses its own set of codecs. As such, differences ARE to be expected.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Which one has the better codecs? And how to have VLC to use the system codecs?

Comment: It depends on what codecs you already have and/or have manually installed. Ubuntu makes it very easy by bundling a lot of video/audio codecs for 99,9% of the typical user's needs in a single easy to install packet. AFAIK there's no way for VLC to use "external" codecs.